# How come the Thevenin Equation is not being satisfied in this simulation?

Tags: simulation, thevenin, multisim, norton

[image]
i1 = 1A 
R1 = 100 Ohm 
R2 = 100 Ohm 
R3 = 2200 Ohm
R4 = 220 Ohm 
R3 and R4 are in parallel.
The first circuit shows that I open circuited at the end to calculate the Voltage across the open circuit which is equal to Thevenin Voltage. It shows 50 V 
My equivalent Resistance where I open circuited the current source, my only source, is 75 Ohms. 
The short circuit current is 500mA which states the current passing through if I short circuit the open circuit. 
The equation:
 `Thevenin Voltage = Thevenin Resistance * Short Circuit current` is not happening here. 
`50 is not equal to 0.5 *75`

Comment: The simulation is right Rth = 50V/0.5A = 100Ω --> Rth = 220Ω||2.2kΩ||(100Ω + 100Ω) = 100Ω [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%281%2F220+%2B+1%2F2200+%2B+1%2F200%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thevenin resistance is 100 Ω. I'm unsure how you calculated it to be 50 Ω: -

[image]